# My MergeSort is showing the wrong output, what do you think is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, mergesort, output

```
    List List:: mergesort(List m)
    {
    if(m.count() <= 1)
           return m;
        else
       {
    List l,r;
        node* temp = m.head;
        node* ptemp = m.head;
        node* first = m.head;
        int c = m.count();
        for(int i = 1; temp->next!=NULL && i<=(c/2)+1; i++)
        {
         ptemp = temp;
         temp = temp->next;
         }

      ptemp->next = NULL;

      while(first!=NULL)
      {
         l.insert(first->data);
         first = first->next;
      }

      while(temp!=NULL)
      {
        r.insert(temp->data);
         temp = temp->next;
      }

      cout<<"\t\t";
      l.display();
      cout<<"\t\t";r.display();cout<<"\n";

      l = mergesort(l);
      r = mergesort(r);
     }
 }
```

I am trying to show each step during the 'divide step of merge sort algorithm.

For example I input this List : 5 3 7 14 2

Desired Output :-

```
              5 3 7 14 2

     5 3 7                  14 2

  5 3      7              14     2

5     3     7           14         2
```

what I get is :

```
              5 3 7 14 2

     5 3 7                  14 2

     5 3                    7             

     5                      3
     14                     2
```

What should I do? I have tried every possible thing, but can't even get close.
Can Any body help, please?

okay this is what i Understand after debugging,
Whats going inside the function mergesort() is:

> mergesort(5 3 7 14 2)
>
> mergesort(5 3 7)
>
> mergesort(5 3)
>
> mergesort(14 2)

What i need is :-

```
mergesort(5 3 7 14 2)
mergesort(5 3 7)   
       mergesort(14 2)   
mergesort(5 3)
```

I can't think of anything. Help please.

Comment: It looks like never get to sorting a right half of anything.

Comment: Why don't you just step through the code in your debugger to see what the problem is ?

Comment: Try to be more specific. Test each unit separately.

Comment: I am done with the debugger, I have to submit this tomorrow, have been working for the last 4 hours. Can somebody give a clearer solution, please?

Comment: @Dr.WickyX put the whole code in codepad so it can be compiled and someone here can debug it

Comment: NO i am not asking that.

Comment: No idea why this is getting down voted. He's even posted expected output and actual output. Much better than typical questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are laying the tree out wrongly. You will never get the 'mergesort tree' displayed like that because you cannot move upwards in console output. Instead you should rotate the tree through 90 degrees. Like this

```
List List:: mergesort(List m, int depth)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < depth; ++i)
       cout << '\t';
   display();
   cout << '\n';

   ...
   l = mergesort(l, depth + 1);
   r = mergesort(r, depth + 1);

}
```

The depth variable controls how much indentation you display before displaying the values you are sorting on this call. Each call's values are displayed on a separate line. This rotates the tree through 90 degrees, so that the root is displayed on the left edge of your console, with child nodes following their parents and progressively further to the right.

Comment: I have tried to do it with gotoxy(x,y); but that doesn't help either.
neither does your method. One of my classmates has done it already. I haven't seen his code. Is it possible with arrays? because I think he is using arrays.

Comment: Sorry my method isn't what you want. It does work on it's own terms however. You can do it with arrays if you like. Basically you  have to do a pass though the algorithm just gathering data (in arrays if you like, but that wouldn't be my choice). Then a second pass to write the information. Seems like a lot of work, personally I would do it my way. Maybe you've misunderstood the requirements?

Comment: no the required output was clearly given in the assignment.ah, got to do this, its a challenge for me now.

Comment: @Dr.WickyX OK, difficult problem then. Mergesort is what they call a depth first routine. But your output is what they call breadth first. To do breadth first you need a queue. That's probably what your classmate is using an array for. I see Dietmar is saying something similar below.

Comment: Lists inside queues... This is going to be very very complex.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would attempt to create a tree like the one you describe (although not exactly identical because `mergesort()` doesn't create another level for a one element sequence) is to build up a tree of intermediate states and then use a [Breadth-First Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) walk of the tree to actually display it. Alternative to actually building the tree as a separate data structure you could implement the `mergesort()` to not use recursion but to control the intermediate steps yourself, effectively using a Breadth-First Search walk of the implicit tree.

Below is an example of what I mean. The output isn't formatted nicely but, at least, each line contains the expected content. Also, the output shows the intermediate results of both the splitting and the intermediate merges.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

using namespace std::placeholders;

typedef std::vector<int> range;

std::ostream& print_range(std::ostream& out, range const& v)
{
    out << '[';
    if (!v.empty()) {
        std::copy(v.begin(), v.end() - 1,
                  std::ostream_iterator<int>(out, ", "));
        out << v.back();
    }
    return out << "] ";
}

std::vector<range>
mergesort(std::vector<range> const& rs)
{
    std::cout << "> ";
    std::for_each(rs.begin(), rs.end(),
                  [](range const& r) { print_range(std::cout, r); });
    std::cout << "\n";
    if (rs.end() != std::find_if(rs.begin(), rs.end(),
                                 [](range const& r) {
                                     return 1 < r.size();
                                 })) {
        std::vector<range> sr;
        std::for_each(rs.begin(), rs.end(),
                      [&](range const& r) {
                          sr.push_back(range(r.begin(),
                                             r.begin() + r.size() / 2));
                          sr.push_back(range(r.begin() + r.size() / 2,
                                             r.end()));
                      });
        sr = mergesort(sr);
        std::vector<range> result;
        for (range::size_type i(0); i + 1 < sr.size(); i += 2) {
            result.push_back(range());
            std::merge(sr[i].begin(), sr[i].end(),
                       sr[i + 1].begin(), sr[i + 1].end(),
                       std::back_inserter(result.back()));
        }
        std::cout << "< ";
        std::for_each(result.begin(), result.end(),
                      [](range const& r) { print_range(std::cout, r); });
        std::cout << "\n";
        return result;
    }
    else {
        return rs;
    }
}

range mergesort(range const& input)
{
    return mergesort(std::vector<range>(1, input)).front();
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        range input{std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),
                std::istream_iterator<int>()};
        mergesort(input);
    }
    catch (std::exception const& ex)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: " << ex.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```